# Read Path in Salesforce

Tags: apex

I am trying find a method to read couple of local drive paths in Salesforce.

**Requirement**

Users want to create a excel sheets containing local drive locations like C:\FilesFolder etc.

When the user clicks on Submit button, the files available on the path of Excel sheet should be read.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What is the intent of the data? loading an excel file in SF is as simple as using an apex:inputfile tag and getting the input.

Comment: Yes this is simple but reading file available on the path specified in the excel sheet and inserting those into notes and attachments or library